# Uncaught ReferenceError: loadImage is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to run this simple Game written in Javascript from my browser (Chrome):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="p5.js"></script>
    <script src="CC Game Alessa Endspiel.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my javascript file which includes the loadimage Code. The Files are all in the same Folder as the js. and index file.

```
var gamestate = "intro";
//Früchte
var Strawberry  = loadImage("Strawberry.png");
var Banana      = loadImage("Banana.png");
var Coconut     = loadImage("Coconut.png");
var Grapes      = loadImage("Grapes.png");
var Pineapple   = loadImage("Pineapple.png");
var Mango       = loadImage("Mango.png");
var Raspberry   = loadImage("Raspberry.png");
var Background1 = loadImage("Background1.jpg");
var Baba2       = loadImage("Baba2.png");
var StartScreen = loadImage("StartScreen.jpg");
var StartButton = loadImage("StartButton.png");
var TimeClock   = 520;
var Princess    = loadImage("indianprincess.jpg");

var player_img = image(Baba2,mouseX,470,19,19);
```

Im totally beginner and hope this is not a too stupid question >.<

**edit**:
thx a lot !

now i added preload function:

```
var Strawberry;
var Banana;
var Coconut;
var Grapes;
var Pineapple;
var Mango;
var Raspberry;
var Background1;
var Baba2;
var StartScreen;
var StartButton;
var TimeClock;
var Princess;

var player_img;


function preload() {

  Strawberry  = loadImage("Strawberry.png");
  Banana      = loadImage("Banana.png");
  Coconut     = loadImage("Coconut.png");
  Grapes      = loadImage("Grapes.png");
  Pineapple   = loadImage("Pineapple.png");
  Mango       = loadImage("Mango.png");
  Raspberry   = loadImage("Raspberry.png");
  Background1 = loadImage("Background1.jpg");
  Baba2       = loadImage("Baba2.png");
  StartScreen = loadImage("StartScreen.jpg");
  StartButton = loadImage("StartButton.png");
  Princess    = loadImage("indianprincess.jpg");

}
function setup() {
  image(Strawberry, 0, 0);
  image(Banana, 0, 0);
  image(Coconut, 0, 0);
  image(Grapes, 0, 0);
  image(Pineapple, 0, 0);
  image(Mango, 0, 0);
  image(Raspberry, 0, 0);
  image(Background1, 0, 0);
  image(Baba2, 0, 0);
  image(StartScreen, 0, 0);
  image(StartButton, 0, 0);
  image(Princess, 0, 0);
  player_img = image(Baba2,mouseX,470,19,19);
}
```

now there is :
Uncaught ReferenceError: noStroke is not defined

and also now i get:

Access to Image at 'file:///C:/Users/Uni/Desktop/CC%20Game%20Alessa%20Endspiel/Banana.png' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

-.-

Comment: Is there an other error that "p5.js" cant be loaded? Take a look at the network tab of your developer tools.

Comment: As you say you are a beginner prefer to name your files without space `<script src="CC_Game-Alessa_Endspiel.js"></script>` prefer a '-' ,'_' or better in camel case.

Comment: "Access to Image at 'file:///C:/Users/Uni/Desktop/CC%20Game%20Alessa%20Endspiel/Banana.png' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access." <-- you should be extremely thankful that this doesn't work. Just imagine if a website could access the `file:` protocol... Oh boy, the disaster that that would be... Just use XAMPP or WAMP and try it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadImage

`loadImage` needs to be called inside an `preload()` function

> The image may not be immediately available for rendering If you want
>   to ensure that the image is ready before doing anything with it, place
>   the loadImage() call in preload(). You may also supply a callback
>   function to handle the image when it's ready.

Can you try that...